# typescript eslint - Type x is missing the following properties from type x

Tags: typescript, eslint, nestjs

So I started a new nest.js project, but I'm my eslint keep giving this error:

> Type 'Task[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Task': id, title, description, statusts(2739)

I have a model.ts

```
export interface Task {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    status: TaskStatus
}

export enum TaskStatus {
    OPEN = 'OPEN',
    IN_PROGRESS = 'IN_PROGRESS',
    DONE = 'DONE',
}
```

and a service on the same folder:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Task, TaskStatus } from './task.model';
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
    private tasks: Task[] = [];

    public getAllTasks(): Task {
        return this.tasks;  <- here
    }

    public createTask(title: string, description: string): Task {
        const task: Task = {
            id: uuidv1(),
            title,
            description,
            status: TaskStatus.OPEN
        };

        this.tasks.push(task);
        return task;
    }
}
```

the method **getAllTasks** is returning the error

and this is my eslint file:

```
module.exports = {
    'env': {
        'es6': true,
        'node': true
    },
    'extends': [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'
    ],
    'globals': {
        'Atomics': 'readonly',
        'SharedArrayBuffer': 'readonly'
    },
    'parser': '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    'parserOptions': {
        'ecmaVersion': 11,
        'sourceType': 'module'
    },
    'plugins': [
        '@typescript-eslint'
    ],
    'rules': {
        semi: [2, 'always'],
        indent: ['error', 4],
        "space-before-function-paren": 0,
        "no-unused-vars": 0,
        quotes: [2, "single", { "avoidEscape": true }]
    }
};
```

I can't see any errors on this piece of code or if I'm supposed to set a new configuration on my eslint to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> private tasks: Task[] = [];
>
> public getAllTasks(): Task {
>         return this.tasks;  <- here
>     }

You are returning `Task[]` in a function that expects to return `Task`. I.e. change the return type to match `getAllTask(): Task[] {`.